# Merging two syntax highlighters in SublimeText

Tags: python, c++, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I am using pycuda, a python wrapper for the Cuda programming language. One of its features is that you write C++/Cuda code in a python string in a python document (see example below).

```
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
   const int i = threadIdx.x;
   dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")
```

I am using SublimeText and just wonder if there is an **easy way** to combine two syntaxhighlighters, namely python and C++, such that the code above is better readable.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm searching for that since quite some time as well. This feature would have helped the PyPy developers a lot, which had lots of python code in string snippets. Right now I need this for XML files, which describe the C++ code insertions of shiboken for generated PySide wrappers...